# FastApi Aio-Pika problem with reconnecting to rabbit Broker after reset

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, fastapi

I am using FastApi(0.78) with AioPika (version 9.0.5) for service which is consuming and publishing  messages with rabbit.
My application is running on k8s in aws structure with aws rabbit broker. Rabbit broker is working in cluster with 3 instances for load balancing messages. Once a week or two aws is making maintenance of broker and is doing it like taking down 1 instance updating it and running again to cluster.
After taking down last instance of broker with old version application is trying to reconnect to broker but its only connecting to new instance of broker but not to the queue with consumer.

My code to achieve consuming from rabbit looks like:

Starting up loop task with consumer:

```
main.py

@app.on_event('startup')
async def startup() -> None:
    """Execute messages consumption on the application startup."""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(consume(loop))

    await task
```

Method which is connecting to rabbit and consumes

```
tasks.py


async def consume(loop: BaseEventLoop) -> Connection:
    """Consume messages from RabbitMQ.

    Args:
        loop: Event loop.

    Returns:
        Aio-pika connection.
    """
    logger.info("Starting messages consumption...")

    conn: Connection = await connect_robust(settings.rabbitmq_url, loop=loop)
    channel = await conn.channel()
    exchange = await channel.get_exchange(settings.rabbitmq_exchange)
    queue_bridge = await channel.declare_queue('queue_name')

    await queue_bridge.bind(exchange, 'queue_name')
    await queue_bridge.consume(on_message)

    return conn


async def on_message(message: IncomingMessage) -> None:
    """Process incoming message with report.

    Args:
        message: Message received from the RabbitMQ.
    """
    async with message.process(ignore_processed=True):
        message_body = json.loads(message.body.decode('utf-8'))

        logger.info("Received message on %s", message.routing_key, extra={
            'body': message_body,
        })

        if message.routing_key == 'routing.key.name':
            Do something with message payload
```

According to aio-pike documentation i should use `connect_robust` which is reconnecting everything (connection, exchange, queue) after losing connection and the application is doing so:

```
Unexpected connection close from remote "amqps:SOMETHING", Connection.Close(reply_code=320, reply_text="CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'")
NoneType: None
Unexpected connection close from remote "amqps:SOMETHING", Connection.Close(reply_code=320, reply_text="CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'")
NoneType: None
Connection attempt to "amqps:SOMETHING" failed: [Errno 111] Connect call failed (SOME IP AND PORT). Reconnecting after 5 seconds.
Connection attempt to "amqps:SOMETHING" failed: [Errno 111] Connect call failed (SOME IP AND PORT). Reconnecting after 5 seconds.
Connection attempt to "amqps:SOMETHING" failed: [Errno 111] Connect call failed (SOME IP AND PORT). Reconnecting after 5 seconds.
Connection attempt to "amqps:SOMETHING" failed: [Errno 111] Connect call failed (SOME IP AND PORT). Reconnecting after 5 seconds.
Connection attempt to "amqps:SOMETHING" failed: [Errno 111] Connect call failed (SOME IP AND PORT). Reconnecting after 5 seconds.
Connection attempt to "amqps:SOMETHING" failed: [Errno 111] Connect call failed (SOME IP AND PORT). Reconnecting after 5 seconds.
```

Application is successfully connecting to new broker instance but not to the exchange and queue(there is no consumer).

I read many issues in aio-pika which said that there was a problem with reconnecting but its solved now. I ran out of ideas what i am doing wrong.

Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a month ago, the connect_robust was not really robust. I took a deep breath and made the switch to [aiormq](https://github.com/mosquito/aiormq). In half a day it was resolved using their explicit connection.closing.add_done_callback(). You have to handle the reconnection yourself at high level but for me it was few lines of code to re-call my whole init/connect sequence.

Note that aio-pika already use aiormq under the hood (it no longer use pika).

Comment: Hi, i havent test your solution but yesterday I found out if I use aio-pika in version 8.2.1 reconnection works as it should. Unfortunately I havent enough time to check library line by line between 8.2.1 and 9.0.5 to find where the problem is.